# getAction Bar() when trying to open camera

Tags: java, android

I have made a file named `profile.java` in which i have provided following code when `onCreate()` is called.It gives an error on `R.color.action_bar`. In my `res` folder i have `values` folder in which i have made a file `colors.xml` with following:

**Colors.xml**

```
<resources>
<color name="bg_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="bg_register">#2e3237</color>
<color name="bg_main">#428bca</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="input_login">#222222</color>
<color name="input_login_hint">#999999</color>
<color name="input_register">#888888</color>
<color name="input_register_bg">#3b4148</color>
<color name="input_register_hint">#5e6266</color>
<color name="btn_login">#26ae90</color>
<color name="btn_login_bg">#eceef1</color>
<color name="lbl_name">#333333</color>
<color name="btn_logut_bg">#ff6861</color>
<color name="view_background">#e8ecfa</color>
<color name="btn_bg">#277bec</color>
<color name="txt_font">#4e5572</color>
<color name="action_bar">#1f2649</color>
</resources>
```

**Code**

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));
```

Any suggestions please. How can i get rid of this error

Comment: *which error* are you getting?

Comment: @LeonAdler i have mentioned the code line in my question

Comment: @tabia You gave us *where* is the error. You did not give us *what* is the error. Apart from the error message itself, please also try to get the stacktrace which may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))`, use `new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar));`

Comment: Now this gives me the `nullpointer exception` :/

Comment: on `getActionBar()`? Or the `ColorDrawable` constructor?